# Join tables from different servers in Oracle - Microsoft Query

Tags: sql, oracle, linked-tables, ms-query, microsoft-query

I'm using Microsoft Query and I want to connect tables from two different servers.

One uses `Oracle in OraClient11g_home1` and the other `MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver`.

Both have DSN setup, a different user and password, one with data source name and the other with an ip and port.

Note that most answers out there might not work with MS Query and Oracle.

Comment: Microsoft Query  can't process an sql statement involving tables from different datasources. Retrieve data as datatables by separate queries and join them in your code. Or create a staging DB for futher processing.

Comment: @Serg So I have to get the data in different queries and work it in Excel VBA right?

Comment: Yes, get the data with different queries. Process as you want in your code.

Comment: @Serg Is it possible to do most calculations in VBA and OLEDB/ADODB connections faster than using QueryTables and putting the data in cells?

Comment: Certainly it depends on calculations needed.